# Unsatisfied Link Error - library loads, entry not found

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface

I'm trying to link a (fairly large) native library written by a client into java
code. I've written this simplified test class that attempts to load the library
and trivially call a native method from the library. I've also added some debugging code.

```
public class JniVtaTest {

  static {
    try {
      Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ldd /usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so");
      byte[] bytes = exec.getErrorStream().readAllBytes();
      System.out.println(new String(bytes));
      bytes = exec.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
      System.out.println(new String(bytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String property = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
    System.out.println(property);

    // above code generates the debugging outpout shown below
    System.loadLibrary("vtajni");
  }

  // running with options:
  // -Djava.library.path="/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -verbose:jni -Xcheck:jni

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JniVtaTest().vtaAnalyze(args[0]);
  }

  private native String vtaAnalyze(String str);
}
```

When I run the above with the noted options, I get a lot of jvm output about dynamic
linking of jvm classes and then this:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe2239d000)
    libiodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbc.so.2 (0x00007ff6093b1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff609028000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff608c8a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff608a72000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff608681000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff60847d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff62713d000)

11.0.5
/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String com.customer.jni.JniVtaTest.vtaAnalyze(java.lang.String)'
    at com.customer.jni.JniVtaTest.vtaAnalyze(Native Method)
    at com.customer.jni.JniVtaTest.main(JniVtaTest.java:26)
```

All of the libraries to be loaded by the library seem to exist:

```
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbc.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec 12  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbc.so.2 -> libiodbc.so.2.1.20
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Dec  4 09:45 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.25
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Apr 16  2018 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.27.so
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96616 Dec  4 09:45 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Apr 16  2018 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 16  2018 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.27.so
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$ ls -al /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Apr 16  2018 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
gus@ns-l1:/usr/java/packages$
```

They are also all findable via `ldconfig -v -N` and I checked that ldconfig doesn't find any 
libraries with the leters `vta` in it like this so I think I'm safe from accidental name overlap:

```
ldconfig -v -N 2>&1 | grep vta
(no output shown)
```

The customer library itself is clearly loaded because when I debug it does not die on load 
library, the debugger will stop on the line invoking the method, and stepping down into 
this JVM code shows that it has found a library named `/usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so` 
and that it enters the for loop first looking for `Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyze`
and then again looking for `Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyze__Ljava_lang_String_2`
(it seems to check twice for each of those)

```
    private static long findNative(ClassLoader loader, String entryName) {
        Map<String, NativeLibrary> libs =
            loader != null ? loader.nativeLibraries() : systemNativeLibraries();
        if (libs.isEmpty())
            return 0;

        // the native libraries map may be updated in another thread
        // when a native library is being loaded.  No symbol will be
        // searched from it yet.
        for (NativeLibrary lib : libs.values()) {
            long entry = lib.findEntry(entryName); <<<<< STOP DEBUGGER HERE
            if (entry != 0) return entry;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The header file generated with `javah com.customer.jni.JniVtaTest`
 looks like this:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest */

#ifndef _Included_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest
#define _Included_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest
 * Method:    vtaAnalyze
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyze
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The method in the cpp file looks like:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyze
        (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring jInputText) {
    cout << "foo";

    // customer code...

    return  env->NewStringUTF(obuf);
}
```

And I never see `foo` printed out so I don't believe it is finding the method 
and then failing inside the method.

Full JDK & system (ubuntu 18.04) info:

```
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)

Linux ns-l1 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hours of searching and reading pages such as https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-do-i-get-unsatisfiedlinkerror- and the spec at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/design.html#resolving-native-method-names have left me scratching my head.

**My question: Why am I getting this error? What have I missed.**

**Edit**: per the question in the comments I don't find the symbol with `nm -D` but I do find something with `nm -A` ... Now i need to figure out why that is.

```
gus@ns-l1:~/clients/customer/code/vta_jni$ nm -A /usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so | grep com_
/usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so:00000000112a3d38 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z44Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyzeP7JNIEnv_P8_jobjectP8_jstring
/usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so:00000000112a388a T _Z44Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyzeP7JNIEnv_P8_jobjectP8_jstring
```

**Edit 2**: The header file is included via...

```
#include "com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest.h"
```

**Edit 3**: After changing the cmake file to use `add_library(vtajni SHARED ...` (and recompiling the client code with `-fPIC`)I now get this:

```
gus@ns-l1:~/clients/customer/code/vta_jni$ nm -D /usr/java/packages/lib/libvtajni.so | grep com_
00000000113587ba T _Z44Java_com_customer_jni_JniVtaTest_vtaAnalyzeP7JNIEnv_P8_jobjectP8_jstring
```

But the name is still mangled, suggesting a second problem with the extern as noted in comments below, but the header IS included as above.

**Solved:** The mangling was due to a forgotten debugging edit which commented out the extern part of the header file in the C project (but the original generated file in the java project that I pasted above still had it) I have now "successfully" caused it to print

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Does `nm -D yourfile.so` list the function?

Comment: nope, that doesn't seem good. hmm..

Comment: Check how you declare visibility in your build and make sure that all the JNI methods are visible

Comment: Not sure how to "check how I declare visibility" ... I've got 18 years of java experience but I'm new to JNI and all my C experience significantly predates my my java experience (Borland Turbo C 1.5). I'm guessing you're speaking of the cmake build?

Comment: From your paste it looks like the header's not being included, because the name is C++ mangled while the header should be ensuring it remains as is through the `extern "C" { ..`. Has the client tested this library or are you modifying it?

Comment: I got their code to work on linux after addressing a bunch of compile errors in their outdated linux version, but my knowledge of cmake and make is very shallow presently thinking this might be due to my using addExecutable instead of addLibrary with "SHARED" ? (based on https://github.com/thefangbear/JNI-By-Examples/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) (though this now gives me other linker errors about relocation...)

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for your help! Your comments were spot on. Feel free to write an answer so I can give you some credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function to work, the exact name must show up with a capital T in `nm -D yourfile.so`. If it doesn't, you have to find out why.

Here's an example file with three functions illustrating common problems:

```
extern "C" {
  void correct();
  extern void notInThisSo();
}
void correct() { }

void missingJniHeader() {}

static void* dummyUsage = (void*) &notInThisSo;
```

Here's the `nm` output (leading zeroes stripped):

```
$ gcc foo.cc -shared -o foo.so && nm -D foo.so
000010f5 T correct                     # This works
         w __cxa_finalize
         w __gmon_start__
         w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
         w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
         U notInThisSo                 # This name is believed to be in another .so
000010fc T _Z16missingJniHeaderv       # This name is C++ mangled: missing extern "C" from header
```

If nothing like your name shows up in `nm -D`, check `nm -A yourfile.so`:

```
$ cat bar.cc
extern "C" {
  __attribute((visibility("default"))) void visible() {}
  void not_visible() { }
}

$ gcc  -fvisibility=hidden bar.cc -shared -o bar.so  && nm -A bar.so
[...]
bar.so:000010fc t not_visible
bar.so:000010f5 T visible
```

Here you can see `not_visible` having a lowercase `t`, because the build used `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide the symbol, and nothing explicitly whitelisted it. JNI can not access hidden symbols.

(If `nm -A` gives `nm: bar.so: no symbols`, it means the library is stripped. You can still use `nm -D` on stripped libraries).